# How to deny object deletion only at specific path level on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I must prevent my users from deleting objects above a certain level of path.
Say that I have the following path structure:

- lavel0

  - level1

    - level2-A

      - level3-A

        - file1.ext
        - file2.ext
    - level2-B

      - level3-B

        - file1.ext
        - file2.ext

I would like to let my S3 users be able to delete objects only starting from level3* included. So basically they should be able to delete **level3-A** and **level3-B** folders but not **level2-A** and **level2-B** neither **level0** and **level1**.
Keep in mind I don't know level2* folder names in advance (but I know level0/level1).

I tried with the following policy with no success (it consequence is that nothing is can be deleted from level1) .

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sid1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Sid2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/level0/level1/*/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is actually possible.

Comment: Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. If objects are created at a certain location (eg `one/two/three.txt`), then the `one` and `two` folders will 'magically' appear. If you create a folder with the **Create folder** button in the S3 console, it will create a zero-length object with a name that ends in a `/`. Is there a reason why you care so much about protecting zero-byte files that represent folders, given that the users are still permitted to delete the actual objects?

Comment: The problem is that when the user uploads a file in a certain folder, S3 triggers an event that invokes a Lambda that does something on the file according to the name of the folder at level2. Deleting that folder just breaks this process.

Comment: How do users upload to the bucket? Are they using an interface that shows the 'folders'? Have you manually created the folders via the **Create folder** button? Please tell us more.

Comment: Users upload to bucket using an S3 client, such as Filezilla Pro. Folders have been created manually. It happens that sometimes users delete folders by mistake, I'd like to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem like this is possible.

The wildcard `arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/level0/level1/*/` will match:

`arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/level0/level1/level2-A/`

and also

`arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/level0/level1/level2-A/level-3A/`

It is merely checking that the ARN starts with `arn:aws:s3:::<<my-bucket>>/level0/level1/` and ends with an additional `/`. It does not specify what might appear between `level1/` and the final `/`.

Therefore, without know the names of the level2 folders, it isn't possible to specify a policy that prevents lower-level folder deletion.